# log4j logging to postgresql not working

Tags: java, postgresql, log4j

This is the database schema

```
create table log4j_messages 
( 
  message  varchar(2000), 
  class    varchar(255), 
  priority varchar(64), 
  log_date timestamp 
);
```

and below is my log4j properties

```
log4j.appender.jdbc=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender 
log4j.appender.jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
log4j.appender.jdbc.URL=jdbc:postgresql://MYSERVER:5432/logs 
log4j.appender.jdbc.user=logs
log4j.appender.jdbc.password=MYPASS
log4j.appender.jdbc.sql=INSERT INTO log4j_messages (message, class, priority, log_date) values ('%m', '%c', '%p', to_timestamp('%d', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,MS'))
```

No data is being logged to the database. Is there anyway I can find out what the problem is?

EDIT:

I tried adding log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG at the top of the properties file and now I get the following warnings.

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (myprogram.Main).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

below is the working version of my log4j properties file when writing to files

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, R, O

# Stdout
log4j.appender.O=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# File
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=log4j.log

# Control the maximum log file size
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=500KB

# Archive log files (one backup file here)
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.O.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}]%5p%6.6r[%t]%x - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.O.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}]%5p%6.6r[%t]%x - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n
```

Comment: Ensure jdbc jar in path. Are you correct log-level(debug /error?)?  Finally - the appender does not log exceptions. http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/jdbc/JDBCAppender.html

Comment: Postgresql expects a point not a comma between the seconds and milliseconds.

Comment: I changed it to a point and still not working. I've also have the jarpath in Eclipse and I also tried putting it in the bin file and the project file.

Comment: could it be because I don't have a log4j.rootCategory at the top of the properties file? when I put one I get errors

Comment: Is the `log4j.properties` included in the jar? It seems like it cannot find it.

Answer (score 2):

You should set the rootCategory to:

```
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, jbdc

log4j.appender.jdbc=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender 
log4j.appender.jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
log4j.appender.jdbc.URL=jdbc:postgresql://MYSERVER:5432/logs 
log4j.appender.jdbc.user=logs
log4j.appender.jdbc.password=MYPASS
log4j.appender.jdbc.sql=INSERT INTO log4j_messages (message, class, priority, log_date) values ('%m', '%c', '%p', to_timestamp('%d', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS,MS'))
```

Else the loggers will not have an appender.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Hiery but when I run my program I get these errors and warnings from log4j pastebin.com/k4UPgftk

Comment: Is the log4j properties file actually included in the jar or the classpath?

Comment: I found something called logback, it's a improved log4j and it's much better documented, I think I should get it working with that.

Comment: You could also switch to slf4j (which is a frontend for all kinds of loggers). And a default implementation of logback.